# Best way to cache data for certain time

Tags: android, caching

I have a situation where admin has defined both **English** and **Spanish** Language at the **admin panel**. Right now, Whatever the changes he made in **admin** **panel**, it is reflecting on the **website**.

My question that when we have different platforms like Android and iOS, Whatever the changes he made in the Admin panel I want it to reflect in the Android as well. As of now, I have defined both language information in **Strings.xml**.

I do not think calling server each time for the **Labels** is a good idea. If i do, it **might slow down** the **app**.

In detail, i have a **validation message** like "**Please Enter User Name**". And the admin changed the label in the back-end and made it **Enter User Name**. Each time calling server to get the information is bad idea. I would like to save the information or data for certain periods. say 2 hours or 24 hours.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What about SQLITE .

Comment: How about caching?

Comment: I think that you have to have a version of your strings. So once your app queries server, it can get the version of strings from the server, and download the delta between your local version and the server version. So if the `validation message` is changed, only this string is downloaded from the server

Comment: You could throw in a small parse-server http://parseplatform.org/

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best solution is to keep it in sqlite. You should check version of strings by calling your API when i.e. application is starting and then update its if necessary.

Unfortunatell queries SQLITE every time when user open new activity/fragment might also slow down your app. In my opinion you should keep your map of string in Application Class or in Object (if you use kotlin) - query your sqlite after checking version of your string or when app is starting if API is unavailable.

Comment: Any link which can help me?